shunt/move message from dlq to another queue
use case: in ibm mq i want to get all messages from DLQ. shunt them to 2 different queues. below is my implementation:
 #!/bin/bash
 #Function to browse messages one at a time and shunt them accordingly

function browseMessages {
  echo "Browsing messages from ${source_queue}"

  while : ; do

    message=$(${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar -Dmq.queue.manager=$mqManager -Dmq.port=$mqPort 
    -Dmq.queue.name=$source_queue -Dmq.host=$mqHost -Dmq.channel=$mqChannel          
    ${APP_PATH}/MQUtil-$jarversion.jar BROWSE -Dmq.count=1 | head -n 1)

    if [ -z "$message" ]; then
      echo "No more messages to browse, exiting loop."
      break
    fi

    echo "BROWSE: ${message}"

    if [[ "$message" == *'BusinessEventType="Amend"'* ]]; then
      shuntMessage "$message" "$AMEND_queue"
    else
      shuntMessage "$message" "$NEW_queue"
    fi
  done
  }

Function to shunt individual messages to the specified queue
 function shuntMessage {

   local message=$1
   local destination_queue=$2
   echo "Shunting message to ${destination_queue}"
   echo "$message" | ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar -Dmq.queue.manager=$mqManager -Dmq.port=$mqPort 
   -Dmq.queue.name=$source_queue -Dmq.host=$mqHost -Dmq.channel=$mqChannel 
   -Dmq.shunt.queue.name=$destination_queue ${APP_PATH}/MQUtil-$jarversion.jar SHUNT
 }

while i build a docker image using this shell script and run it it stucks at
browsing message 0.....
when i tested the browsing functionality indivisually.. it works..
function browseTop3Messages {
  local queue=$source_queue
  local count=3
  local action="BROWSE"

#Invoke the MQUtil jar with the BROWSE command and limit the count to 3
 ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar -Dmq.queue.manager=$mqManager -Dmq.port=$mqPort 
  -Dmq.queue.name=$queue  -Dmq.host=$mqHost -Dmq.channel=$mqChannel
  -Dmq.count=$count 
  ${APP_PATH}/MQUtil-${jarversion}.jar ${action}
}

is the issue with shunting the messages??
when i tried just to browse it worked. but when i try to browse and filter and then shunt.. it does not work.. my doubt is how i am am trying to shunt the message. please suggest

Are the messages on the DLQ originally for two different queues?

th mssages in the DLQ ar of two kinds.

businessEvnt=new.. time, entity.. other attributes...
businessevnt=new..time, entity.. other attributes..businessevent=amend...time, entity.. other attributes.

so a message can be new and stay new for rest of its lifecycle..
or a message can start as new and later it can be updated (hence amend)...
goal is to we will filter out amend mesage and put/shunt to a amend queue.
it i cant find amend  keyword in the message body then i will shunt to new queue.

Was the original destination queue the same for both types of messages?

This is an inefficient way to move messages. Even if it works you are opening and closing a connection twice for every message.
Your working version passes mq.count as an environment variable.
-Dmq.count=$count 
  ${APP_PATH}/MQUtil-${jarversion}.jar ${action}

The failing version passes -Dmq.count=1 as an application argument.
${APP_PATH}/MQUtil-$jarversion.jar BROWSE -Dmq.count=1

I guess your application can only handle the count being set as an environment variable. In which case you should use
-Dmq.count=1 
  ${APP_PATH}/MQUtil-${jarversion}.jar BROWSE

That said, even if you do fix the bug, don't do it like this.
